# How do you uninstall Visual Studio 2008 SP1 w/ .Net 3.5 SP1?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

What's the best way to uninstall SP1 and return to plain .Net 3.5 with Visual Studio 2008?  It broke a few of my programs  :(

Answer (score 6):

It should be visible in Add/Remove programs if you check the "Show updates" box.

[This link](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/F/D/8FD2A9F0-C3D4-4B0A-80AF-88D738DCDDF4/VSReadme.htm#Uninstalling) lists the series of updates that need to be uninstalled for the SP1 Beta.  The uninstall for the final RTM version may be similar.  (I don't have VS2008 in front of me now, so I can't confirm until tonight).

Comment: Thank you. For final, it should say "Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 [Edition] - ENU Service Pack 1 (KD945140)".